# requests.post gives 204 but curl and os.system run just fine

Tags: python, curl, subprocess, python-requests

I am trying to get the response of a http post request using python. I am using Python 2.7.3
I need to get the response of the http post request I make.
I tried using the requests module to do the following:

```
import requests
import urllib
url = "http://"+server+":"+port+"/myService"
data = urllib.urlencode({'name':name, 'description':description, 'tags': tags, 'status': status})
response = requests.post(url, data = data)
```

For this, I get a 204 response. But the curl command from terminal was running just fine. So I tried using `os.system` to run curl command, which works fine. But the problem is that now I was not able to get response status. `os.system` returns a 0.
I also tried using the `subprocess` module

```
import subprocess
params = "name="+name+"&tags="+tags+"&description="+description+"&status="+status
proc = subprocess.Popen(['curl', '-X', 'POST', '-d', 
                                params, url], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
(out, err) = proc.communicate()
print out
```

For this, it prints the following:

```
% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   101    0     0  100   101      0   1712 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1741
```

And printing `out` prints nothing. Please help.

Comment: As a side note, if the only reason you're creating a `Popen` is to immediately call `communicate` with no input, just use one of the convenience methods, like `check_output`.

Comment: Anyway, to debug your actual problem, you have to look at what's different between the request `curl` sends and the request `requests` sends. You can't do that by guessing; you have to either point them at something you can watch (like netcat) (or I guess you could capture the data over the wire, but that's a lot more work for no more benefit…), or read the documentation to see how to ask them each what they're going to send.

Comment: `204` also means that everything went "just fine" (that's the definition of 2XX responses). What result were you actually expecting?

Comment: @Ivo I am expecting a 200.

Comment: Have you tried the `requests` code without the `urlencode` call (just passing in the dictionary?) This seems like a weird thing to do with the requests library.

Comment: @Ivo, yes. Tried that too. I guess I will have to consider a 204 resoponse as success.

Comment: 204 is a success. Its just a success with no content

Comment: I'm curious -- did the curl get a 204 also? Try running `curl` with the `-D headers.txt` switch.

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [HTTP/1.1 standard](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html):

> > 10.2 Successful 2xx
> >
> > This class of status code indicates that the client's request was successfully received, understood, and accepted.
> >
> > ...
> >
> > 10.2.5 204 No Content
> >
> > The server has fulfilled the request but does not need to return an entity-body ...

Your POST was a success in every sense of the word.